# Terraform - reference output variable to one of child modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am having some troubles on one of my references a terraform structured project.
Trying to use an output of two subnet ID's in to EKS terraform, but when I'm trying to do `terraform plan` or `terraform apply` the results I'm getting that it will create new subnet for me, which is not true because I already created one on the previous step at 1-vpc/main.tf

Important to say that I've ran the `1-vpc` terraform first for the output variables to be available for the 2nd run of `2-eks` dir.

Folder structure:

```
terraform
└───1-vpc
│   │   main.tf
│   │   output.tf
└───2-eks
│   │   main.tf
│   │   output.tf
```

inside the 1-vpc output.tf I have the following:

```
output "subnet_a" {
  description = "Subnet A block"
  value = aws_subnet.subnet_a.id
}
output "subnet_b" {
  description = "Subnet B block"
  value = aws_subnet.subnet_b.id
}
```

and on the 2-eks main.tf file I'm trying to reference:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "../1-vpc" # Source all the output variables
}

resource "aws_eks_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  name     = "my-cluster"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster_role.arn

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = [ module.vpc.subnet_a, module.vpc.subnet_b ]  
  }
```

I tried to follow the guide by terraform https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/outputs#accessing-child-module-outputs without any help.

Comment: did you first run terraform in your `1-vpc` dir first to depoy the VPC, now you have switched dir to `2-eks` and running terraform again there?

Comment: If so that wont work. cause your EKS setup is saying you want to deploy a new VPC and an eks cluster. its using the module 1-vpc to deploy it. if you want to deploy the VPC and the EKS together you should make a new main.tf in the root of your terraform dir and call to module 1 and module 2 and pass the outputs of module 1 to module 2

Comment: @ChrisDoyle comment is most likely root cause as executing the above listed config as the root module would not cause this behavior, and "I already created one on the previous step at 1-vpc/main.tf" heavily impplies subnet management outside of the config, and more specifically by using the first module as another root module.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle sorry for the misunderstanding, yeah I will add that to the question as well, I ran first the ```1-vpc``` and then switched to ```2-eks``` dir

Comment: Then of course it will try to create you a new network as that's what you have asked it to do. See my comment above about creating main.tf in the common dir and refer to both dirs as modules

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would structure it:

```txt
terraform
│   main.tf
│   
└─── vpc
│   │   vpc.tf
│   │   output.tf
│   
└─── eks
│   │   eks.tf
│   │   output.tf
│   │   variables.tf
```

Then `main.tf` will put it all together

```hcl
module "vpc" {
  source = "./vpc"
}

module "eks" {
  source     = "./eks"
  subnet_ids = [ module.vpc.subnet_a, module.vpc.subnet_b ]
}
```

That is all, like that the modules stays independent, and the "entry" point to the code is at the parent folder not inside a module, I'm sure as your application grows you will need many more modules, this way keeps it clean and easy to understand for any other developers.

---

Something you might not notice, there is a new `variables.tf` under the eks directory, that is where we define the input `subnet_ids` and you can add there any other parameter you might need, here is a sample code:

```hcl
variable "subnet_ids" {
  type = list(string)
}
```